# libvpx configure script wrong path for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, configure, libvpx

I'm trying to build libvpx 1.3.0 under Visual Studio 2012 (vs11) under windows 8.1 (x64).

I read the build prerequisites (http://www.webmproject.org/code/build-prerequisites/) and configured libvpx as following:

```
./configure --target=x86-win32-vs11 --disable-examples --disable-docs --disable-unit-tests
```

After the configure i do a `make`, without errors. But when i lauch the solution under Visual Studio and try to build, i get those path error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: obj_int_extract, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  obj_int_extract.c
1>c1 : fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '.\\home\Thomas\libvpx-v1.3.0\build\make\obj_int_extract.c': No such file or directory
2>------ Build started: Project: vpx, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>cl : Command line warning D9002: ignoring unknown option '/home/Thomas/libvpx-v1.3.0/vp8/encoder/vp8_asm_enc_offsets.c'
2>cl : Command line error D8003: missing source filename
2>  'obj_int_extract.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2>  operable program or batch file.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(124,5): error MSB3073: The command "call obj_int_extract.bat /home/Thomas/libvpx-v1.3.0
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(124,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I tryed both MSYS and Cygwin, same result.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem fixed:

The 1.3.0 snapshot seems to be faulty, cloning the git was the solution, it will probably be gone in the next snapshot.

Configured with Cygwin, MSYS was missing a perl module.